# Unable to copy file "obj\x86\debug\myForm.exe" The process cannot access the file ... error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The full error:

> Unable to copy file "obj\x86\debug\myForm.exe". The process cannot
>   access the file  'bin\debug\myForm.exe' because it is being used by
>   another process.

This is an infamous bug with VS I've read that many people have. All things I've researched have pointed me in the direction of not properly "Cleaning up" all of the resources the program uses, so I've included two lines in my formClosed event handler for the application, but that has still not solved the problem. Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Service_Control_Panel {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        const string serviceName = "AgentService";
        ServiceController sc;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
          sc = new ServiceController("AgentService");
          statusRefresh.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            sc.Start();
        }

        private void stopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           sc.Stop();
        }

        private void statusRefresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            statusBox.Text = Convert.ToString(sc.Status);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

I am honestly at a loss as to why this is an issue. On top of this the program is not running in the Task Manager's processes tab as "myForm.exe" or what have you. And the only way I can finally build a new version after making changes is if I restart my system! Not even restarting VS resolves this.

Comment: Does closing VS and re-opening solve the problem? Also check if there is some hidden process still running (like a hidden instance of your program). Or it might even be your anti-virus.

Comment: As I said at the bottom of my posting this does not resolve my problem. Only restarting the workstation solves this issue, and then when I make another, even simple change, I am back to not being able to build.

Comment: What version of VS do you have? This really sounds like even though you stop running the program, SOMETHING is still using the file, either the program is still running in the background, or another programming (like anti-virus) is holding onto the file.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Professional Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel

Comment: Just to note. I have Avast installed, but while I am developing I disable it completely to allow me ease of access to the system.

Comment: It seems I have solved the problem! I will post the answer as soon as I am allowed!

Comment: Disable Avast, it is famously incompatible with VS.

Comment: You can try to use procmon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see who locks the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try close, dispose and then release the reference to the service.  This MSDN article talks about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx

```
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        sc.Close();
        sc.Dispose();
        sc = null;
        //kill is unnecessary.  I'd just stick with app exit.
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: This was, in essence, my issue. The service I had made had a reference to the forms application that was involved in this problem, and even though the service was not opening the program it had made a reference to it and thus was using it and keeping a new version from copying over the old one. Thanks for your help!